# How to create global middleware on Express?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, routes, middleware

I'm working on a geolocation service and I need to make middleware that will be doing its job on every subpage, **but only 1 time**

I have tried to do something like

`userRegion`

```
module.exports = (req, res, next) => {
   console.log('123')
   next()
}
```

But in console, I get a lot of `123`. It works more than 1 time. I tried to add the route.

```
app.use('/api', userRegion)
```

But still, in the console I get a lot of `123`, so, it's incorrect too.

In general, the task looks like this.

1. Global middleware
2. Works on every page (subpage)
3. And does its work only **1** time

How can I do that? Thanks for the answers!

Comment: Sorry, i did not understoond this point from above "And does its work only 1 time", 
Each time you hit API, the middleware will get executed. Also I cannot see you middleware code you wrote or using? 
Can you add more details

Also this is ref on how to write middleware
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/nodejs-creating-your-own-express-middleware

Comment: Code with `console.log()` is middleware. This is just for test. I have create this middleware, and made it 'global'. But when I hit API, I get this `123` more than 1 time. Like `123
123
123
123
123
123
123
123
`

Comment: What is `userRegion` , i believe  that is middleware file 
Can you paste you both files in detail here?

Comment: Here you go, check code

Comment: Looks like the client is sending multiple requests to `/api` or the middleware is registered multiple times for a route. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Yeah, that's true.
`/en/category/gift-cards
/_nuxt/runtime.js
/_nuxt/commons/app.js
/_nuxt/vendors/app.js
/_nuxt/app.js
/_nuxt/pages/_language/category/_slug/index.js
/_nuxt/vendors/pages/_language/about-us/pages/_language/account/security/pages/_language/account/transactio/5c959889.js
/_nuxt/vendors/pages/_language/about-us/pages/_language/account/security/pages/_language/account/transactio/7d1df54e.js
/_nuxt/vendors/pages/_language/category/_slug/index.js
`
This is what I got by `console.log(req.path)`

Comment: `only once` that is against the default concept of middleware. if you want  that to only once keep track whether that sub page is visited or not in somewhere ie in DB and check that logic inside this middleware.

Comment: How do you even know that two requests belong to the same subpage. The user could visit page 1, start loading the dependencies, abort loading page 1 and start loading page 2.